# Find closest value to 0 in range of values in Excel (with non-numeric fields)

Tags: excel, min, absolute-value

I have a range of cells in Excel with various positive and negative numbers. The value of the cell is determined by an IF formula, and some of the cells in the range have no value ("").

I need to find the absolute value of the nearest cell to 0. So if I had a list of -10,-5,-1, 3, 6, and "": I need to get a result of 1.

I've tried multiple approaches but the fact that I have non-numeric cells seems to be an issue which is causing errors.

What I've tried:

`{=Min(ABS(A1:D10))}`, where I press Ctrl-Shift-Enter (returns an error because of non-numerics)

`{=IF(MAX(D3:D22)<=0,-1,IF(MIN(ABS(D3:D22))=MIN(ABS(IF(D3:D22>0,D3:D22,MAX(D3:D22)))),1,-1))*MIN(ABS(D3:D22))}`, where I press Ctrl-Shift-Enter (returns an error because of non-numerics)

`{=IF(OR((D3:D22)>0),MIN(ABS(D3:D22)),-MIN(ABS(D3:D22)))}`, where I press Ctrl-Shift-Enter (returns an error because of non-numerics)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
=MIN(ABS(IF(ISNUMBER(D3:D22),D3:D22,9999)))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

should do the trick

or better use:

```
=INDEX(D3:D22,MATCH(MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(D3:D22),ABS(D3:D22))),ABS(D3:D22),0))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

doesn't care about text or empty cells but having 0 as number will count... also negative numbers will be negative (if you allways want positive you need to `ABS` the whole formula...

Comment: Interesting -- we were typing essentially the same answer simultaneously. That shows that the answer is somewhat natural.

Comment: If you make the ABS part of the IF statement, i.e. MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(D3:D22),ABS(D3:D22)), then you do not require a value_if_false clause.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an upper bound, say 10^9, on what the min is you can do:

```
{=MIN(ABS(IF(ISNUMBER(D3:D22),D3:D22,10^9)))}
```

If you find it problematic to make any assumptions about what the min is, note that it is certainly less than 1 + the absolute value of the maximum number, so you could use:

```
{=MIN(ABS(IF(ISNUMBER(D3:D22),D3:D22,1+ABS(MAX(D3:D22)))))}
```

Comment: @DirkReichel Thanks. I tested the formula using a different range and tried to modify it by hand to reflect OP's range but must have mis-counted parentheses or something

Comment: If you make the ABS part of the IF statement, i.e. MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(D3:D22),ABS(D3:D22)), then you do not require a value_if_false clause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this only because it worked for me before the other users came in with their answers. I'll still accept one of their answers rather than this.

```
=MIN(IF(D3:D22>0,D3:D22,ABS(D3:D22)))
```

> And of course I had to press
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how one finds the number closest to zero when the values are not in contiguous cells? (i.e., not in a 'range') For example, `a1`, `b5` and `f15` contain the values -3, 4 and -5. The formula should return the value -3.

Tom Ogilvy at https://www.atlaspm.com/toms-tutorials-for-excel/ answered the question:

For the specific question you asked, this would return -3

```
=INDEX(CHOOSE({1,2,3},A1,B5,F15),MATCH(MIN(ABS(CHOOSE({1,2,3},A1,B5,F15))),ABS(CHOOSE({1,2,3},A1,B5,F15)),0))
```

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. You can adjust the `CHOOSE({1,2,3},A1,B5,F15)` (which replaces the `C7:C20` in the original formula) to include more cells. For example if I wanted to add `Z20` and `AA4` I could use `CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5},A1,B5,F15,Z20,AA4)`. Each cell would need to be listed individually. so you could not have `CHOOSE({1,2},A1,B5:B20)`